# Поиск по тегам и именам

Tags: php, sql, laravel, поиск, search

У меня в базе три таблицы (данные в таблицах для примера):

```
    files
| id | name |
|  0 | cat  |
|  1 | dog  |

    tags
| id | tag    |
|  0 | animal |
|  1 | gray   |
|  2 | black  |

    file_tags
| file_id | tag_id |
|       0 |      0 |
|       0 |      1 |
|       1 |      0 |
|       1 |      2 |
```

Мне нужен поиск по всем переданным ключевым словам, чтобы искало и в тегах и в именах файлов. Чем длиннее запрос, тем точнее поиск.
Точно такой же поиск в закладках у Firefox'а.

Примеры:

```
Запрос: animal
Найдет: file cat и file dog

Запрос: cat
Найдет: file cat

Запрос: animal,gray,cat
Найдет: file cat

Запрос: animal,gray,dog
Найдет: ничего

Запрос: cat,dog
Найдет: ничего
```

Для поиска только по тегам я нашел решение:

```php
public function search(string $search)
{
    $searchArr = explode(",", $search);

    $files = File::whereHas("tags", function($query) use ($searchArr)
                                    {
                                        $query->whereIn("tag", $searchArr);

                                    }, "=", count($searchArr));
    return $files->get();
}
```

Но как к этому добавить поиск и в именах файлов? И если не с помощью Laravel, то хотя бы как сделать на голом SQL.

Comment: *как к этому добавить поиск и в именах файлов?* А чем он отличается? да ничем - кроме имён поля и таблицы, вместо "tags" будет "files", а вместо "tag" будет "name".

Comment: @Akina Если добавить аналогичное условие, только с поиском по файлам, то например для набора `animal,gray,cat` ничего не будет найдено. Потому что поиск по тегам не будет равен кол-ву элементов в `$searchArr`(у нас 2 тега и 1 имя в массиве).

Comment: *поиск по тегам не будет равен кол-ву элементов в `$searchArr'* o_O и не должен... если юзер смешал теги и файлы в кучу - то твоя первая забота их разгрести обратно в две кучки. И по каждой отдельненько искаться. Кстати, а что ты станешь делать, если какое-то слово окажется и в таблице тегов, и в таблице файлов?

Comment: Мне бы наоборот сгрести в одну кучу и показать. Если пользователь помнит что файл назывался кот и на изображении был серый кот, почему бы пользователю не ввести запрос `серый кот`, отсекая при этом всех рыжих котов? И если слово дублируется и в теге и в файле, я тоже не вижу в этом проблемы, файл `кот`, у него теги `кот, серый`, в чем тут проблема?

Comment: Есть два слова в поиске. Одно ("кот") надо искать и в файлах, и в тегах, другое ("серый") - только в тегах. Если искать только в тегах - нагребёшь лишнего, если и там, и там - не найдёшь нужного.. а как ты собираешься различать, где искать - и там, и там, или только в одном из вариантов (и каком именно)?

Comment: А как мне тогда различить, что пользователь ввел имя или тег?

Comment: Не, нормально... я-то откуда знаю? если даже разработчик не в курсе... Я бы вообще забил на это дело - вот тебе релевантность, и радуйся, а что в нужном попадается хрень, или что-то нужное не нашлось - так это претензии не ко мне, а к кривым алгоритмам полнотекста.

Comment: Иными словами - вали всё в кучу, и файлы, и теги, а потом ищи. Типа `select * from files join files_to_tags join tags where (name in tokens) and (tag in tokens)`, а потом уже смотри на релевантность полученных пар и количество пар для каждого значения с каждой из сторон связи.